# How can I split data day-wise?

Tags: amazon-redshift

So my data looks something like this:

| Created_at. | Updated_at. |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-2022 23:40 | 2-1-2022 24:20 |
| 2-1-2022 24:50 | 2-1-2022 01:15 |
| 3-1-2022 22:10 | 4-1-2022 24:30 |

I have to calculate the duration between them day-wise. So, I want my table to look like this:

| Created_at. | Updated_at. |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-2022 23:40 | 2-1-2022 24:00 |
| 2-1-2022 24:00 | 2-1-2022 24:20 |
| 2-1-2022 24:50 | 2-1-2022 01:15 |
| 3-1-2022 22:10 | 4-1-2022 24:00 |
| 4-1-2022 24:00 | 4-1-2022 24:30 |

Comment: You are sure about "24:20" as time? And you are sure that "24:50" is BEFORE "01:15"?

Comment: Yes! The day ends at 23:59:59. So, 24:00:00 is considered as 00:00:00

Comment: but `24:30` or `24:20` aren't valid time value in Postgres

Comment: Corrected the tag issue

Comment: And still: Created at "2-1-22 24:50" and Updated "2-1-22 1:50" makes no sense...

Comment: To make it clear, let's suppose a battery was put on charging at {{created_at}} and was disconnected from the charger at {{updated_at}}. Now , I want to check the duration a battery was on charge in a day(24 hours) and clasify them according to dates. According to the above data, battery was put on charging for 30 mins on 4-1-2022 and so on